Replacement for Google Fit REST API with new Health Connect?
I have a website where my fitness stats can be publicly seen.
In order to achieve that, I've used the Google Fit REST API, but now I see that it's gonna be removed in 2025, stating you gotta migrate to Health Connect API.
The problem is that I don't see anywhere in the documentation any REST API available to get the data, so my guess is I should develop an app which gathers the data and then connects to my server.
I saw like a month ago they were willing to keep the REST API but only removing the on-device API, but now even the REST API gets a message of deprecation (which is new).
Will there be or is there a REST API for Health Connect? I really would like to avoid having to make my own app (specially because I'm and iOS user, but I don't wanna pay, nor use HealthKit from Apple, which would be the next way to go if Google Fit removes their API).
Thanks in advance!

currently looking for a alternative myself, as far as I can understand the REST API is being deprecated without a replacement, which is extremely frustrating, as I too want to develop my web based stats dash for my own use as I much prefer that to looking at a phone.
one possible route I found was a project like this creating a gateway to connect to health connect via a REST API, though I've not tested it yet and it does not seem to be maintained and I'd not use it without understanding its code first. Hopefully we'll see more solutions like this going forwards, if google is not forthcoming with a REST API for health connect.

Yep, this seems fairly recent, I did my project like 2 months ago and there was no sign of deprecation for the REST API, only for the Android one. I guess we'll have to wait to see what Google has to offer in the future, but Health Connect I think is not an option for me as an iOS user.

Has anybody figured out a workable solution for this?
